# React Native: App crashes in simulator only when debugging is on and only on Android

Tags: android, react-native

I have a react native app running on RN 0.48.4. It runs fine on the iOS simulator with debugging on or off.

When I run it on the Android simulator (I have tried both the simulator included with Android Studio and Genymotion) it works fine when the remote debugger is off, but crashes when the debugger is on at launch.

It crashes at various points in the first few seconds after launching the app, not always at the same place, with the error: "Unfortunately, myApp has stopped". I can not find anything to indicate what is causing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am running with the exact issue with that version of react-native. I had to downgrade it to version 0.47.0 to debug the app.

Comment: That did fix it. For me the cause was the Realm module. Issue here: https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/1294#issuecomment-330540448